# Difference between measure zero and volume zero?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, volume

I have the following definitions for a set to have measure zero and for a set to have volume, respectively:

A set $A$ has measure zero if for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a covering $\{S_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} \mathrm{vol}(S_i) < \epsilon$.

A set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ has volume if the characteristic function of $A$ is integrable. That is, $\int_A 1_Adx$ exists.

My questions are: 1) What is the difference between the measure of a set and the volume of a set? 2) Specifically, is having volume zero stronger than having measure zero? I have the following example: $\mathbb{Q}$ has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (since $\mathbb{R}$ does), but $\mathbb{Q}$ does not have volume since $1_\mathbb{Q}$ is discontinuous everywhere, thus having measure zero does not imply a set has volume zero. Is there a nice example of question 2) above? 3) What is the geometric difference and meaning of volume versus measure? Is there a context in which one is not strong enough for a certain result (i.e. why bother making two definitions?) I have not had too much exposure to topology (which is where I suspect this distinction pops up) or Lebesgue integration, so simply giving an example without too must justification is okay with me.

Comment: For 1), you have only defined measure zero, defining the (Lebesgue) measure takes more machinery. Without getting into details, a function is Riemann integrable **iff** the set of points of discontinuity has measure zero. Hence a set has volume **iff** its boundary has measure zero. Having volume is more restrictive than having measure.

Comment: I have seen this in class, but I must not have thought of it when I asked the question. Do you have anything for questions 2) and 3)?

Comment: Well, volume zero implies measure zero and there are sets that have measure zero but no volume. So, I would just say that having volume is more restrictive rather than stronger. I'm not sure there is a nice geometric interpretation for 3). Loosely, volume requires that it behave nicely in the sense that the limits over finite partitions converge, where as measure is much more versatile, since, again loosely, it allows countable operations. The example you gave above, the rationals, is a nice example.